# What's the name of this lovely plant?

Tags: identification

My mother wants to know what this plant in her new garden is. Please help since I have no clue.

It's South Korea here btw.

[image][image][image]

Answer (score 3):

It looks like [Schefflera actinophylla](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schefflera_actinophylla), or an umbrella tree. I've got one as a house plant, but I hear they grow wild and as weeds in Florida and maybe warm parts of California.

Comment: They'll get 30 - 40 feet tall in So Cal.